# Authentication with OAuth2 in Webflux Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, spring-webflux, okta

I'm developing an app, in which i want to have role-based access control, unfortunately I didn't find any good example with spring webflux usage. 
My oauth2.client.provider is Okta.

Here is my SecurityWebFilterChain:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/admin").hasRole("admins");
}
```

In [this article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/13/okta-groups-spring-security) I've found that I should configure resource server. Give me a hint how to do it,please.

Comment: This article should work better for you: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/24/reactive-apis-with-spring-webflux

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in this article is simple configuration, without role-based access control.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a milestone release of Spring Boot 2.1 for this to work. M3 or higher should do the trick. Add the necessary dependencies for Spring Security 5.1 OIDC support:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then create an Okta OIDC "Web" app and copy your settings into `src/main/resources/application.yml`.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          okta:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-737523.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default
        registration:
          login:
            okta:
              client-id: {clientId}
              client-secret: {clientSecret}
              scope: openid email profile
```

Restart your app, go to http://localhost:8080, and you should be redirected to Okta to log in. Enter valid credentials, and you'll be redirected back to your app after a successful log in.

To limit access based on roles, you'll need to create groups for your users.

Create a ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER group (**Users** > **Groups** > **Add Group**) and add users to them. You can use the account you signed up with, or create a new user (**Users** > **Add Person**). Navigate to **API** > **Authorization Servers**, click the **Authorization Servers** tab and edit the default one. Click the **Claims** tab and **Add Claim**. Name it “groups” or “roles”, and include it in the ID Token. Set the value type to “Groups” and set the filter to be a Regex of ".*" (to include them all).

Then you should be able to use something like:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
```

You should also be able to use `@PreAuthorize` as mentioned in [this blog post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/26/build-a-spring-boot-webapp%22this%20blog%20post%22).

Comment: I've done it, but it's not role-based access control

Comment: I updated my answer to include role-based access control.

Comment: I've tried it before. When i'm trying to load "/admin", i'm getting "Authentication required" pop-up window. I'd like to be redirected to okta login page.

Comment: You may need to add `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` to your configuration class. Probably a `.and().oauth2Login()` too. See this class for an example: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-webflux-react-example/blob/react-app/reactive-web/src/main/java/com/example/demo/SecurityConfiguration.java